# jQuery count A HREF inside table

Tags: jquery, count

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    var totaltr = $("#catlist_ul").html().find('a').length; 
    $('#cog1').hide();
    var htmlBlock = "<strong>" + totaltr + " ITEMS</strong>";
    totalProductList.innerHTML += htmlBlock;
});

<table id="catlist_ul">
<tr><td><a href="#">link</a><a href="#">link</a></td></tr>
<tr><td><a href="#">link</a><a href="#">link</a></td></tr>
</table>
```

Should return 4 ITEMS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All you need is:

```
$('#catlist_ul a').length
```

[`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html) gets the `innerHTML` of the provided selector, which is not what you want. Please review the [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com)

---

Instead of using `jQuery(document).ready`, you should use the aliasing shortcut:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
  //same as $(document).ready()
});
```

Comment: This is actually faster than my original code. Smaller in lines too. +Rep and marked. jQuery is brilliant.